# Appending Header Tags Dynamically in jQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a page in HTML which has a header, content, and footer divs.

```
<div data-role="page" id="Homelist" >
    <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>heading</h1>
        <a href=""/></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
          <img>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" >
           <h3>show</h3>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Below the `h1` tag, I have to add an `h3` and `h4` tag from a JavaScript file.

I will have a value in JavaScript file say "`var header2 = "mini-header";"`. Can I use the `header2` value in my HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the content of any element to what ever you want to using jquery:

Html:

**Note:id**

```
 <div data-role="header" id="header">
      <h1>heading</h1>
      <a href=""/></a>  
 </div>
```

Javascript to change content:

```
$("#header").html("<h1>heading</h1><h2>heading2</h2><h3>heading3</h3><a href=''/</a>");
```

Where # is the id selector.Go through jQuery documentation.

To use a value of a javascript variable:

```
var myheader="header3";
$("#header").html("<h1>heading</h1><h2>heading2</h2><h3>"+myheader+"</h3><a href=''/</a>");
```

Comment: after adding this lines how can i display the particular html page??

Comment: Can you please provide a JSfiddle of what you are trying to do?So that its more clear.